# Why the table pg_stat_user_tables is blank?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am new to postgres.

I am checking the stats in table pg_stat_user_tables but i didn't get any results. It says 0 rows found.

Any idea how this table get updated?
Is there any parameter to enable the stats ?

Thanks

Comment: Is [`track_io_timing`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-IO-TIMING) enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because there are no user tables in that database (the database contains only system tables).

Use `pg_stat_all_tables` to get information about all tables in the database.

Comment: is user here refers to the database name  ?

Comment: Both `pg_stat_all_tables` and `pg_stat_user_tables` contain only tables in the same database. While the former contains all tables, the latter will not show system tables.

Comment: Yes if both database shows tables.. then why my pg_stat_user_tables is blank ? Infact i have lot of tables in postgres schema, any idea ?

Comment: If you create a table, vacuum it and there is no entry in `pg_stat_user_tables`, something is very wrong. Either is it not normal PostgreSQL, or there is data corruption.

Comment: It's importante to be aware of executing the query from the schema you need the information, for example executing the function pg_stat_user_tables in postgres schema won't return any data(it happend to me ) as there are no user tables in this schema.